# How to deploy class file on WildFly 11?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, wildfly, devops

Ho to deploy class if a issue is fixed in a Web application running on WildFly?

If using Tomcat instead of WildFly, I will deploy the class in webapps/my-app/classes/ with package directories in order to minimize an influential range of the changes.
After Deploying war file into standalone folder. war folder is not extracting as like tomcat?So how to change jsp or else class file? Please help on the same.

Comment: How do you deploy your application?

Comment: Deploying .war file in standalone/deployment/ folder. and run my application as standalone.

Comment: It's really not advised to edit files directly like that, but if you deploy it exploded you should be able to.

Comment: After deploying war file,same has not been exploded.That is the main issue.Can u give me some suggestion how to explode my war file after deploying.

Comment: You'd have to deploy it exploded instead of an archive. You'd just add the directory to the deployment directory. Something like your-app.war which would be a directory. See the README.txt in the deployment directory and http://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/11.0/subsystem/deployment-scanner/scanner/index.html. FWIW in newer versions of WildFly there are other ways to do it.